# Read the location of memory in linked list for next node

Tags: c

I am writing a code to read the address of the node in linked list so can some one confirm if `%p` and `%u` format in printf is correct. One gives me the hex and other gives me a decimal and conversion to hex or deci are matching. Also it will be great if someone can brief on difference of `%p` and `%u`.

```
struct node {
    int x;
    struct node *next;
};

int main () {
    struct node *root;
    struct node *track;

    root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf ("Location of root is %p\n", root);
    printf ("Location of root is %u\n", root);
}
```

Output of execution:

```
[root@vm c_prog]# ./a.out 
Location of root is 0xdc3010
Location of root is 14430224
[root@vm c_prog]# ./a.out 
Location of root is 0x11fbf010
Location of root is 301723664
[root@vm c_prog]# ./a.out 
Location of root is 0x7e8e010
Location of root is 132702224
[root@vm c_prog]#
```

Comment: 0xdc3010 == 14430224. you can verify by adding a %x specifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%p` is for a pointer, and is correct.  Strictly speaking, you should cast to `void *`, but I've never met an implementation that cared.  Example:

```
printf ("Location of root is %p\n", (void *)root);
```

`%u` is for an `unsigned int` and is *not* correct, unless you play some casting gymnastics and are sure a pointer and an `int` are the same size.  To safely print a pointer value in decimal, you should use `PRIuPTR` from `inttypes.h`:

```
printf ("Location of root is %"PRIuPTR"\n", (uintptr_t)root);
```

Comment: so its %p that I should be using if I want to know the address allocated for each node in linked list. In case of int variable I will have to use & in printf, right?

Comment: If you want to print the address of that `int`, yes.

Answer (score 2):

the difference is that %u = unsigned int, and %p = pointer... these may not be the same size on your system/arch, and shouldn't be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `%p` prints a pointer in whatever format the implementation sees fit (usually hex - and that's what you are seeing now), and %u prints an unsigned integer. If you use %x instead, you may get a more similar result. However, `%p` also understands the size of a pointer, which in a 64-bit system isn't the same as a integer, which is what `%u` or `%x` will print.

Technically, `%p` also 'only' works with void pointers.